# Forms Authentication and Login controls

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-membership, asp.net-2.0

I am upgrading a website written using ASP.NET 1.1 and the logic for the login page includes verifying the credentials, calling `FormsAuthentication.SetAuthCookie()` and populating the Session with the user information.

I am updating this page to use Login controls and the Membership API and am trying to wrap my head around the concepts that have been changed.

1. Most of the samples I see do not do anything on the login button event handler, so is the logic of setting the cookie abstracted out into the control?
2. Also, how do I check if a user is logged in or not on other pages. Does it still store user information using the Session?
3. How do I check if a user belongs to a particular role or not (Earlier, I would look in the Session object to do something like this)
4. Is the Session a bad way of storing user info?

Thanks

Comment: Thanks for the downvote. Unfortunately not everyone's smart and fast enough like you, to keep up with the ever changing technology.

Comment: Did I downvote your question? I simply stated why I would not be interested in spending time composing an answer that either 1) contained only links to 1 of the 15,700,000 results that are a result of a 'how to use asp.net 2.0 membership' google query, the topmost being some of the most comprehensive overviews you could get or 2) duplicating the information I just noted. Your question seems to demonstrate a lack of initiative. I never said nor implied anything regarding your intelligence.

Comment: If you read my question carefully, you will notice that it has less to do with "'how to use asp.net 2.0 membership" and more about how authentication has conceptually changed from 1.1 to 2.0. When I said "Most of the samples I see.. " did that demonstrate the lack of initiative?

Comment: First: when you want to converse with someone, me in this instance, in comments be sure to use the reply convention which will ensure that the comments are delivered to my inbox - e.g. @codepoet. That said, you may notice that I have no problem answering a wide variety of questions, asp membership in particular http://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged?tagnames=asp.net-membership&sort=stats&pagesize=50 What you are asking here is for someone to spend time duplicating information that is WIDELY available and is in no way difficult to discern.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're using membership along with the login controls, the api handles authenticating the user when the login button is clicked. You can also handle the event if there is other stuff you need to do when a user logs in. If you don't use membership, you'll need to handle the login click and authentication yourself.

you don't necessarily need to check if a user is logged in if you have the authentication set up correctly in the web.config, but if you have pages that logged in users and anonymous users can both access you might want to look at the loginview control. You can also check if a user is logged in using the **Page.User.Identity.IsAuthenticated** method.

To check if a user is in a role, just use **Page.User.IsInRole("role name")** or **System.Web.Security.Roles.IsUserInRole("username", "rolename")**

I don't think session is a bad way to store user info, but if you're using membership then I don't see the point.